# Windows: copy file to new folder if there is no duplicate

Tags: batch-file, cmd

A month ago I've made a backup of d:\source to f:\backup1 using robocopy:

```
robocopy d:\source\ f:\backup1\ /zb /XJ /COPY:DAT /e /v /R:1 /W:1
```

Now I want to make a new backup f:\backup2 of d:\source and copy only files that don't exist in f:\backup1 or they have been changed (there is no duplicate in f:\backup1).

How to do that using cmd.exe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run `robocopy` in list-mode ("dry-run") using the first backup folder to build the list of updated/new files, then manually copy the files from that list one by one:

```dos
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "source=d:\source"
set "backup1=f:\backup1"
set "backup2=f:\backup2"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
    robocopy "%source%" "%backup1%" /s /e /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl /l
') do (
    echo %%a
    set "file=%%a"
    set "dir=%%~dpa"
    md "!dir:%source%=%backup2%!" 2>nul
    copy /y /b "%%a" "!file:%source%=%backup2%!" >nul
)
```

N.B. this simplified code won't handle file names with `!`